# I get an ERROR initiating a background job

Tags: plsql, ifs-erp

I'm trying to initiate a background to the server, but I get errors.
This is my PL/SQL script:

```
DECLARE
    attr_ VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
    client_SYS.Clear_Attr(attr_);
    Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('LINE_ITEM_NO_','8', attr_);
    Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('ORDER_NO_','92298', attr_);
    Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('RELEASE_NO_','*', attr_);
    Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('SEQUENCE_NO_','*', attr_);

    Transaction_SYS.Deferred_Call('SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC_API.Unreserve', 'PARAMETER', attr_,'Description' );
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I get this ERROR from the background job:

```
"Argument INFO_ is of type IN/OUT or OUT, which is not supported. ORA-20105: Transaction.WRONG_ARGUMENT"
```

The procedure needs an info_ argument (Please see the function declaration below,) så I add this line:

```
Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('INFO_',NULL, attr_);
```

But I get THE ERROR:

```
too many decalrations OF 'ADD_TO_ATTR' match this CALL


SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC_API.Unreserve(info_         => ,
                                  attr_         => ,
                                  order_no_     => ,
                                  release_no_   => ,
                                  sequence_no_  => ,
                                  line_item_no_ => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction_SYS.Deferred_Call an only be executed with Procedures with **IN** type parameters. PLSQL functions or Procedures with IN OUT, OUT parameters are not supported.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but thanks anyway. Is there anyway out of this problem. Would it be possible to create a new deferred_call that ignores the OUT parameters?

Comment: There's no standard way provided by IFS but what we usually do is create a custom Procedure which has only IN parameters which is called by `Transaction_SYS.Deferred_Call` and inside that calls the standard IFS Procedure or Function.

Comment: OK, so do I, but I would be convenient to be able to start a deferred call from an event action. Thanks